# Strip Some Part Of URL And Save File

Tags: python

```
http://amz.com/New-Balance-WT910-Trail-Running/dp/B0098FOFCW/ref=zg_bsms_shoes_2
```

I don't need the last `/ref=zg_bsms_shoes_2`

I have the values in the `urls=[]`

```
for productlink in products:
    self.urls.append(productlink)

def save(self):
    self.br.quit()
    f=open(self.product_file,"w")
    for url in self.urls:
        f.write(url+"\n")
        f.flush()
```

How to strip it? Also with a fail proof if I don't have /ref=?

Comment: You may use regular expression to strip it.

Comment: @IdleMind I think url.replace is better choice less resources :) but still I'm not sure how to do it correctly I'm new to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> x = 'http://amz.com/New-Balance-WT910-Trail-Running/dp/B0098FOFCW/ref=zg_bsms_shoes_2'
>>> '/'.join(x.split('/')[:6])
'http://amz.com/New-Balance-WT910-Trail-Running/dp/B0098FOFCW'
>>> y = 'http://amz.com/New-Balance-WT910-Trail-Running/dp/B0098FOFCW'
>>> '/'.join(y.split('/')[:6])
'http://amz.com/New-Balance-WT910-Trail-Running/dp/B0098FOFCW'
```

Comment: '/'.join(x.split('/')[:-1]) might be preferable

Comment: @Guy can you explain [:6]? what about the scenario of: `'http://amz.com/New-Balance-WT910-Trail-Running/dp/B0098FOFCW/'` "/" at the end

Comment: [:6] will simply take first 6 elements from the list, will always return without last `/` do you ask how to add it?

Comment: @Guy weird but trying it `for productlink in products:
            '/'.join(productlink.split('/')[:6])
            self.urls.append(productlink)` didnt seem to work

Comment: `for productlink in products: x = '/'.join(productlink.split('/')[:6]) self.urls.append(x)`

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly encourage you to start with `urlparse`:

In python3:

```
>>> import os
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> os.path.split(urlparse(url).path)[0]
'/New-Balance-WT910-Trail-Running/dp/B0098FOFCW'
```

`urlparse` will turn the URL into all its component pieces and then you can work with the path in any number of ways, simple string splitting, `os.path.split`, regex, whatever you like.

In Python2 just use `from urlparse import urlparse`

Answer (score 1):

```
if 'ref' in url.split('/')[-1]: #Failsafe
    url = '/'.join(url.split('/')[:-1]
```

Comment: a[-1]    # last item in the array
    a[:-1]   # everything except the last item

Comment: `for url in self.urls:
            if 'ref' in url.split('/')[-1]: #Failsafe
                url = '/'.join(url.split('/')[:-1]
            f.write(url+"\n")
            f.flush()` `f.write(url+"\n")
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` any idea why?

Comment: Under which line and character is the ^  exactly ?